# How do I make an console application run until the user enters "Q", "q", "Quit" or "quit" to terminate it?

Tags: c#, console-application, exit

How do I make an console application run until the user enters "Q", "q", "Quit" or "quit" to terminate it?

This is my current code:

```cs
public class Class1
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string userName;
    int i = 0, totalCal = 0, cal = 1;

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the magical calorie counter!");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Enter in your name -> ");
    userName = Console.ReadLine();

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}.....Let's add some calories!!", userName);
    }// end for loop

    Console.WriteLine();

    while (cal != 0)
    {
      Console.Write("Enter some Calories:<or 0 to quit>: ");

      cal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

      Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", cal);
      Console.WriteLine();

      totalCal += cal;
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("-------------------So far you have a total of {0}------------------", totalCal);
      Console.WriteLine();    
      Console.WriteLine();
    }// end of while 
  }// end of amin
}//end of class
```

Comment: I recommend you ask this on: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ctrl + C is by far the best :)

Comment: "Dear sir and/or madaam, I respectively wish to discontinue my usage of this computer program. I request that all activity in this program cease henceforth and forthwith. Thank you for your consideration in this matter. Yours, Z."

Comment: Am I the only one who understood the question? He wants to know how to make the program quit by typing one of those commands.

Comment: Exactly, I just didn't explain it properly. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @NullUserException - I didn't understand until you pointed it out.

Comment: @Chris - Please edit your question to improve clarity.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming there aren't any other bugs in your program... just add a couple lines like this:

```
using System;

class Class1
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userName;
        string line;
        int i = 0, totalCal = 0, cal = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the magical calorie counter!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Enter in your name -> ");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();

        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}.....Let's add some calories!!", userName);
        }// end for loop
        Console.WriteLine();


        while (true)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter some Calories:<or 0 to quit>: ");
            line = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            if (line == "q" || line == "quit")
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (!int.TryParse(line, cal))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid option. Please try again.");
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", cal);
            Console.WriteLine();

            totalCal += cal;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------So far you have a total of {0}------------------", totalCal);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }// end of while 
    }// end of amin
}
```

Comment: ahhhh, wrong loop to start with, but i see how that works. Thanks Mark.

Comment: then make it `while(true)` instead. +1 or a checkmark would be nice.

Comment: mark, i need 15 rep to give you a check mark, anything other way i could do it?

Comment: @Chris: Really? Thats kind of dumb... well I just gave you 10 pts, so.. I guess you'll have to wait for the other 2 :p Fill out your profile to get 100 I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think exit, or quit is fine. Or you can accept e or q.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer a keyboard shortcut a keyboard savvy user **may** already know, like Ctrl+W, which is the default key for closing tabs on modern web browsers.

Comment: And i'd prefer that a console app act like a console app, not Firefox or Chrome or whatever.  Keyboard shortcuts aren't just a pain to type and remember; they just don't make sense in a program like this, and add complexity to the reading of input.